# Which dependency will Gradle choose given multiple maven repository?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In Gradle project, we can define multiple remote / local Maven repository.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jCenter()
        maven { 
            url 'https://example1.mavenrepo.com/public'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://example2.mavenrepo.com/release"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.example.mydependencies:mylibrary:1.0.0'
    }
}
```

If `mylibrary` exist in all of Maven repo. Which one will Gradle choose? Can I configure Gradle to only download `mylibrary` in certain Maven repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can find in [the doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#sec:repositories_tutorial)

> A project can have multiple repositories. Gradle will look for a dependency in each repository **in the order they are specified, stopping at the first repository that contains the requested module**.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to point to the gradlew to use particular repository or order it. Gradlew by design uses a single repository for all dependencies. If any of them fail, the build fails.
[Refer]: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7965